# Is the warp of spacetime caused by mass infinite in radius, or does it completely flatten?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mass, metric-tensor, curvature

So the mass (=energy) of the sun warps space, creating a dip.  Does this well stretch infinitely, but just gets so subtle it cannot be noticed, or does it actually cut off at a point?

Comment: I think you've gotten a good answer, but you might be a little too heavily bought into the "ball on a trampoline" or "gravity well" visualizations, which are faulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In General Relativity, a mass curves spacetime all the way out to infinity, just as in Newtonian gravity a mass exerts gravitational force on other masses all the way out to infinity. There is no cut-off distance. At some point the curvature is just “too subtle to be noticed”, as you said.

Curvature is complicated. In general it takes 20 numbers at each point in 4D spacetime to express it. (This is the number of independent components of a mathematical object called the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor).) Usually we boil down that complexity to some relevant “curvature scalar”, a single number that expresses a kind of “average curvature”.

For a Schwarzschild black hole, the invariant that is linear in the curvature, called the [Ricci scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature), is actually zero, even though various components of the Riemann curvature tensor are nonzero.

But there are also quadratic curvature invariants and they are nonzero. For example, for a Schwarzschild hole the [Kretschmann scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar) is

$$K=\frac{48G^2M^2}{c^4r^6},$$

so you can very loosely imagine “the curvature” as dropping off like $1/r^3$.

Comment: I believe the ultimate "too subtle to be noticed" point would be the distance at which telescopic magnification of the objects affected would require energy exceeding that available in our observable region, although the situation is complicated by gravitational lensing around intermediate objects, which would tend to provide some natural magnification.  (Correction of these notions would be welcome.)